Pandas apply function behaving differently based on input size?
I have a function which works fine with a tiny Pandas Dataframe and returns the adjustments as expected,
but when I apply it to a non-test Dataframe, which is only a small df (300 x 20), it gets completely messed up.
Using the example below as a reference, it would populate columns 3 - 7 with the same list of values for all rows in each respective column...
To add to the confusion, when I remove the code from within the function and run it as part of one file the expected results are achieved for the non-test dataframe...
Can anyone suggest what might be happening here and why the behaviour seems to vary? / what I am changing.
I provide the code here for recreation
def test_populate_columns_from_Key_Value_String():

    starting_df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "Names": ["Sarah", "John"],
            "Relations": [
                "has parent: Maggie, is parent of: Tom, is parent of: Grace, is parent of: Bart, is related to: Grandpa Simpson, is hated by: Joseph",
                "is friends with: Tracey, has parent: Greg",
            ],
            "has parent": [[], []],
            "is parent of": [[], []],
            "is related to": [[], []],
            "is hated by": [[], []],
            "is friends with": [[], []],
        }
    )

    desire_df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "Names": ["Sarah", "John"],
            "Relations": [
                "has parent: Maggie, is parent of: Tom, is parent of: Grace, is parent of: Bart, is related to: Grandpa Simpson, is hated by: Joseph",
                "is friends with: Tracey, has parent: Greg",
            ],
            "has parent": [["Maggie"], ["Greg"]],
            "is parent of": [["Tom", "Grace", "Bart"], []],
            "is related to": [["Grandpa Simpson"], []],
            "is hated by": [["Joseph"], []],
            "is friends with": [[], ["Tracey"]],
        }
    )

    starting_df.apply(
        populate_columns_from_Key_Value_String, axis=1, args=("Relations",)
    )

    print(starting_df)
    assert desire_df.loc[0, "has parent"] == starting_df.loc[0, "has parent"]
    assert starting_df.loc[0, "is hated by"] == ["Joseph"]
    assert starting_df.loc[1, "is friends with"] == ["Tracey"]
    assert starting_df.loc[0, "is parent of"] == desire_df.loc[0, "is parent of"]

def populate_columns_from_Key_Value_String(
        row: pd.Series, column_to_extract_from="Column_name_with_Relational_String"
    ):
        string_to_extract_values_from = row[column_to_extract_from]
        if isinstance(string_to_extract_values_from, str):
            for key_value_pair in string_to_extract_values_from.split(","):
                if isinstance(row[key_value_pair.split(":")[0].strip()], list):
                    row[key_value_pair.split(":")[0].strip()].append(
                        key_value_pair.split(":")[1].strip()
                    )


So the code you posted works, but it fails with a larger df? There must be something different in the structure of the production df, and we're not going to be able to figure out what you did differently.

Have you tried reducing the non-test dataframe in size until it stops messing up?

I don't know if this answers your question, but you could avoid the custom function and extractall the X: Y pairs, then pivot_table:
out = starting_df[['Names', 'Relations']].join(
  starting_df['Relations'].str.extractall('(?P<col>[^:,]+): *([^:,]+)')
  .droplevel(1).reset_index()
  .pivot_table(index='index', columns='col', values=1, aggfunc=list)
  # optional: only if you need empty cells as empty lists
  .map(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, list) else [])
)

Note that you could use a split approach instead of extractall: starting_df['Relations'].str.split(', ').explode().str.split(': ', expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'col'}).pivot_table(...)
Output:
   Names                   Relations  has parent  is hated by        is parent of      is related to has parent is friends with
0  Sarah   has parent: Maggie, is...          []     [Joseph]  [Tom, Grace, Bart]  [Grandpa Simpson]   [Maggie]              []
1   John  is friends with: Tracey...      [Greg]           []                  []                 []         []        [Tracey]

Intermediate before the pivot_table:
               col                1
0       has parent           Maggie
0     is parent of              Tom
0     is parent of            Grace
0     is parent of             Bart
0    is related to  Grandpa Simpson
0      is hated by           Joseph
1  is friends with           Tracey
1       has parent             Greg


Thanks, mozway; this approach is fine and I will use your advice so thank you. Not accepting as I don't think it answers the original question.

I cannot prove this is the cause, but I had not been explicitly setting the  function output using the return or updating the resulting dataframe using the = operator and was treating them as updating in place.
When I explicitly assigned them, everything worked.
I'm not going to accept this answer just yet because I cannot justify my answer.
def test_populate_columns_from_Key_Value_String():

starting_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Names": ["Sarah", "John"],
        "Relations": [
            "has parent: Maggie, is parent of: Tom, is parent of: Grace, is parent of: Bart, is related to: Grandpa Simpson, is hated by: Joseph",
            "is friends with: Tracey, has parent: Greg",
        ],
        "has parent": [[], []],
        "is parent of": [[], []],
        "is related to": [[], []],
        "is hated by": [[], []],
        "is friends with": [[], []],
    }
)

desire_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Names": ["Sarah", "John"],
        "Relations": [
            "has parent: Maggie, is parent of: Tom, is parent of: Grace, is parent of: Bart, is related to: Grandpa Simpson, is hated by: Joseph",
            "is friends with: Tracey, has parent: Greg",
        ],
        "has parent": [["Maggie"], ["Greg"]],
        "is parent of": [["Tom", "Grace", "Bart"], []],
        "is related to": [["Grandpa Simpson"], []],
        "is hated by": [["Joseph"], []],
        "is friends with": [[], ["Tracey"]],
    }
)

starting_df = starting_df.apply(
    populate_columns_from_Key_Value_String, axis=1, args=("Relations",)
) # Change made here in non test script but just pointing it out here for reference.

print(starting_df)
assert desire_df.loc[0, "has parent"] == starting_df.loc[0, "has parent"]
assert starting_df.loc[0, "is hated by"] == ["Joseph"]
assert starting_df.loc[1, "is friends with"] == ["Tracey"]
assert starting_df.loc[0, "is parent of"] == desire_df.loc[0, "is parent of"]

def populate_columns_from_Key_Value_String(
    row: pd.Series, column_to_extract_from="Column_name_with_Relational_String"
):
    string_to_extract_values_from = row[column_to_extract_from]
    if isinstance(string_to_extract_values_from, str):
        for key_value_pair in string_to_extract_values_from.split(","):
            if isinstance(row[key_value_pair.split(":")[0].strip()], list):
                row[key_value_pair.split(":")[0].strip()].append(
                    key_value_pair.split(":")[1].strip()
                )
    return row # Change made here in function

